# how to convert time php so that it converts PT to CT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to convert time from my default site time which is PT to new york, I only want to convert it once pulling it from the database heres my code

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles') ;
$site_time = date("H:i:s",time()) ;
```

this inserts the time in PT

```
$insert_chat = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO chat (time) VALUES 
'$site_time'" );

$select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT time FROM chat") ; 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){

     $chat_time = $row['time'] ;
```

after  I pull the PT time from database I would like to convert to new york CT

```
     date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York') ;

     $user_time = date("h:i A",strtotime($chat_time)) ;

     echo $user_time ;
```

But when I echo the time its still showing PT , what am i doing wrong

Comment: If this is new data, I'd recommend storing time in a timezone non-specific method, like UTC, and then converting on display or output. This way, when you move your operation to another timezone, you don't have to worry about which time your database currently holds. If you already have data stored, you might be pretty set with what you need to do anyway.  DISCLAIMER: I _HATE_ dates/times.

Comment: ay thanks man thats so true bro , using just the default time() is the same as using 'UTC' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution using PHP standard objects:

```
$dt = new DateTime(
    '2017-01-01 09:00:00',
    new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')
);
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $dt->format("h:i A"); // 12:00 PM
```

What happens in your code is that `$chat_time` has no timezone associated with it; it's just a string. Calling `date_default_timezone_set` has no bearing on it. When you call `date` it only formats the string.

Comment: so is it correct to enter my default time  like this $dt = new DateTime(date(Y-d-m H:i:s), new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') ?

Comment: Not sure whats wrong but when i enter  $dt = new DateTime(
  date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()),
    new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')
); its giving me 9:51 but its 11:51 in los angeles right now

Comment: If you call `time()` it will use the global timezone in the execution environment. Calling `date_default_timezone_set` at a point earlier in the code will change that global timezone. If your case you already have the time as a string (`$chat_time`). You can plug that variable where I put the time-string in my code (line 2). Then by creating a new DateTime object with a time-string and DateTimeZone object, the DateTime object becomes configured and can be mutated (`setTimezone`) and triggered to print output (`format`).

Comment: HECK yea i get what your saying now , ay thank bro i appreciate the detail